# Register an image using mutual information

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, synthetic-aperture-radar

I want a procedure for registering two images based on their mutual information. I took a pair of georeferenced radar images of the same location, edited the metadata of one so its position was off by about a km, then tried to use mutual information in the ENVI image registration workflow to correct the position of the edited image so it matched the unedited image. The result was a horrible warp that did not correct the problem at all. 
The images have near identical conditions (there's a very slight change in brightness values, but nothing that should be a problem).

How can I use mutual information in ENVI to register a pair of images?